# Why does `bash -c somecommand` sometimes not leave a bash process?

Tags: bash, shell, process

On an Ubuntu 12.04, with GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu),
I tried the following command:

```
$ bash -c 'pstree -s $$'
init───sshd───sshd───sshd───bash───pstree
$ bash -c 'pstree -s $$;echo'
init───sshd───sshd───sshd───bash───bash───pstree
```

I think the second one is as my expectation: the first `bash` is where I executed these commands; the second `bash` is what I started with `bash -c ...`; and then the second bash will start a subprocess called `pstree`.

However, I'm wondering what happened with the first one. Why the second `bash` disappeared and the `pstree` became a subprocess of the original `bash`? And why the answer for the previous question doesn't apply to the second `bash -c ...`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would have said that it is simply [Tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) [Call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) [Optimization](http://jeapostrophe.github.io/2012-05-28-exec-vs--post.html), but in fact (as the last link points out), `bash` doesn't optimize tail calls. It only seems to optimize the case where the command to be executed is a simple command (that is, not a compound command) though not when there are redirections. It also seems to optimize when the command is the last in an and-or list (as in `true && true && cmd` or `false && true || cmd`) but not when there are `trap`s in place (as in `trap uname EXIT && cmd`) as it would be incorrect to do so.

The second command is not a tail call of `pstree`, because `pstree` is not the last thing in the command line. (It's a tail call of `echo`, but `echo` is usually a built-in so no subprocess will be created for it regardless.)

To save reading all those links (although I hope they are interesting), the idea is that if you know that a function/program/whatever will return immediately after calling some other function/program/whatever, and that the value returned will be the value returned by the called function/program/whatever, then you might as well just reuse the current stack frame (or process, in the case of a shell script) instead of pushing a new stack frame (creating a new process), calling the function (running the script), and then returning. In a shell script, you can do that manually by using `exec` for the last command, but it would be possible for the shell to do that automatically.

`zsh` and `ksh` both seem to be able to do that, but not `bash`:

```
$ zsh -c 'if [[ -n foo ]]; then pstree -s $$; else echo hello; fi'
init───lightdm───lightdm───init───konsole───bash───pstree
$ ksh -c 'if [[ -n foo ]]; then pstree -s $$; else echo hello; fi'
init───lightdm───lightdm───init───konsole───bash───pstree
$ bash -c 'if [[ -n foo ]]; then pstree -s $$; else echo hello; fi'
init───lightdm───lightdm───init───konsole───bash───bash───pstree
```

But that observation is just an observation, based on the versions of those shells which I happen to have installed, so YMMV:

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```